# How to get File using Blob Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, file, rxjs, blob

I have a form and download file button my problem is why i cant sent what i input in my form at the same time with my download file?

```
  this.fg = this.fb.group({
        rptReqCode:[''],
        rptCode:[''],
        parFldVal:[''],
        genType:[]
    })
  }



downloadFile( filename: string = null): void{

  const token = 'my JWT';
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('authorization','Bearer '+token);
  this.http.get(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'File/Download'  ,{headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}).subscribe(
      (response: any) =>{
          let dataType = response.type;
          let binaryData = [];
          binaryData.push(response);
          let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
          downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: dataType}));
          if (filename)
              downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
      }
)}
```

Comment: Hi Alluring
What are you using server side?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you want to send data to the server you use POST, if you want something for the server you use POST.

You have a couple of options:

POST user data, then use `switchMap` to concatenate the request and the download you file using the GET request.

Another option is to use the POST request to send your data and as a response you will receive the file. You have to make some changes in your Backend.